# Net::ReadTimeout Error when Watir::Browser.new

Tags: ruby, watir, irb

**I'm trying to start watir browser,**

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'watir'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> browser = Watir::Browser.new
```

Watir opens a new chrome browser with `data:,`wrote in the search bar. After 60 seconds of waiting, the browser just closes, and I'm getting this error in console:

```
Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:136:in `readuntil'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:146:in `readline'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1437:in `block in transport_request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1434:in `catch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1434:in `transport_request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1407:in `request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1400:in `block in request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1398:in `request'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.14.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:121:in `response_for'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.14.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:76:in `request'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.14.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:62:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.14.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:164:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.14.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:97:in `create_session'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.14.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:53:in `handshake'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.14.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:48:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.14.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:44:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.14.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:44:in `for'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.14.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:86:in `for'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/watir-6.13.0/lib/watir/browser.rb:48:in `initialize'
    from (irb):3:in `new'
    from (irb):3
    from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

**How could I solve this issue?**

Comment: @sawa, how could I solve this issue? What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @sawa what's not clear for you?

Comment: @Rajagopalan As I wrote, the question was not clear before the edit.

Comment: @sawa Okay, Fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said this happens when page load exceeds 60 seconds, you can increase the page load timeout by the following code

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.read_timeout = 120 # seconds
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox,http_client: client
b=Watir::Browser.new driver
```

Now your code would wait for 120 seconds for any page load which has been caused by #click and also wait to load the url by goto method.

Comment: As of `watir` version 6.19.0, they provide their own HTTPClient so you can just do something like this: `Watir::Browser.new :firefox, http_client: { read_timeout: 120 }`

Comment: @Joshua Pinter Yes I am aware of that. I have done that change in my work. The above answer is very old.

Answer (score 1):

#### `watir` [6.19.0+](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/main/CHANGES.md#6190-2021-03-12)

As of watir version 6.19.0, they provide their own HTTPClient so you can just do something like this:

```rb
Watir::Browser.new :firefox, http_client: { read_timeout: 120 }
```